# Using metal business card holders as RFID wallets

Tags: rfid

I have been reading about RFID technology and products.  Are metal business and/or credit card holders viable substitutes for RFID wallets? Are all metal wallets Faraday cages?

Comment: What is an RFID wallet? Maybe you meant RFID-_blocking_ wallets?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer: yes.

A metal case, whether it is solid or a fine enough mesh will block RFID.